# running sums, find blocks of rows that sum to given list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is the test data:

```
declare @trial table (id int, val int)

insert into @trial (id, val)
values (1, 1), (2, 3),(3, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5),(6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 2),(9, 3), (10, 4), (11, 6),(12, 10), (13, 5), (14, 3),(15, 2)  ;

select * from @trial order by id asc
```

description of data:
i have a list of n values that represent sums. assume they are (10, 53) for this example. the values in the @trial can be both negative & positive. note that the values in @trial will always sum to the given sums.

description of pattern:
10 in this example is the 1st sum i want to match & 53 is the 2nd sum i want to match. the dataset has been set up in such a way that a block of consecutive rows will always sum to these sums with this feature: in this example, the 1st 4 rows sum to 10, & then the next 11 rows sum to 53. the dataset will always have this feature. in other words, the 1st given sum can be found from summing 1 to ith row, then 2nd sum from i + 1 row to jth row, & so on....

finally i want an id to identify the groups of rows that sum to the given sums. so in this example, 1 to 4th row will take id 1, 5th to 15th row will take id 2.

Comment: SQL-2016? You probably mean MS SQL Server 2016...

Comment: What if the values do not exactly add up?

Comment: yes ms sql server 2016, apologies

Comment: the values will always add up :)

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original question.

From what you describe you can do something like this:

```
select v.grp, t.*
from (select t.*, sum(val) over (order by id) as running_val
      from @trial t
     ) t left join
     (select grp lag(upper, 1, -1) over (order by upper) as lower, uper
      from (values (1, 10), (2, 53)) v(grp, upper)
     ) v
     on t.running_val > lower and
        t.running_val <= v.upper
```

Comment: well, that was quick :) thanks. ill get back to you soon

Comment: im getting a null group id for the last 3 rows?

Comment: ive noted in question that row id 5 - 15 should take group id 2 in this example

Comment: `.....select grp, isnull(sum(upper) over(order by grp rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as lower, sum(upper) over(order by grp) as upper
  from (values (1, 10) .....`

Comment: i should clarify that values can be both positive & negative as edited sometime ago

Comment: @lptr does negative & positive complicate issue too much? is it solvable?

Comment: @charliealpha . . . Ask another question with a clear and complete description of the problem.  I don't answer "evolving" questions.

Comment: "i have a list of n values. assume they are (10, 53) for this example." sorry i didnt realize id have to clarify that the values are not constants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ive given detailed explanation now. apologies if it wasn't clear. does description help? let me know if you want more examples. thanks for your help. im really stuck.